# Firebase Crashlytics for iOS: close not symbolicated issues

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have some crashes in the Firebase Crashlytics console with missing `dSYMs`, so the console shows an alert icon, requiring me to upload dSYMs manually.

But the problem is these `dSYMs` were already overwritten and don't exist on the computer anymore, so it's not possible to make these issues available in the main issues list.

Does anybody know, is there any way to delete/close these issues at least?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not so many years passed, and Crashlytics added solution, it's on a dSYMs tab:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used a workaround. Crashlytics wants dSYMs before we can do anything with crashes? Ok, we'll give him.

Even if original dSYMs for crashed build are lost (or weren't generated), you may take version of project closest to crashed version and generate dSYMs (that's why it's good to have version control). If you can't find dSYMs, make sure they're enabled in build settings:

[image]

The problem is - generated dSYM will have another UUID, and Crashlytics won't match it with crashes to symbolicate. Here we do a hack, replacing UUID in generated dSYM with one of missing dSYM in console.

1. Find generated dSYM UUID in packet's info (CMD+I > "More info" > "dSYM UUIDs"):

[image]

2. Locate dSYM file in generated dSYM packet (open packet with "Show packet contents"):

[image]

3. Open file with any HEX editor (I used [Hex Fiend](https://apps.apple.com/ru/app/hex-fiend/id1342896380?mt=12) from AppStore) and locate UUID (it's in the beginning of file); notice that it will be raw bytes, not a UUID string:

[image]

4. Replace generated UUID with one of missing dSYM, save, upload dSYM to console.

That's all. If you're lucky enough, crash may be correctly
symbolicated; otherwise you'll at least be able to close it)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. Todd from Crashlytics. Right now it's not possible to force close these crashes, though that's an interesting idea. Once you launch a new version you have dSYMs for these will be less visible in your dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for answer.